# Error while creating comma separated list from data-frame to pass into SQL query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a comma separated list to pass SQL query.

**my code**

```
sql1 = '''select carrier_name, carrier_account, invoice_number, invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date
from invoice_summary where invoice_number in {}'''.format(tuple(data1['invoice_number'].values.tolist()))
```

**Current Output**

```
    "select carrier_name, carrier_account, invoice_number,
 invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date\nfrom invoice_summary where invoice_number in ('BHX3327983',)"
```

**Expected Output**
"

```
select carrier_name, carrier_account, invoice_number,
     invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date\nfrom invoice_summary where invoice_number in ('BHX3327983')"
```

I am looking for a solution that works when there is single input or there mutliple inputs to be passed.

Whats wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `join` and put the parenthesis inside the string:

```
sql1 = '''select carrier_name, carrier_account, invoice_number, invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date
from invoice_summary where invoice_number in ({})'''.format(','.join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in data1['invoice_number']]))
```

---

#### Update

You could use the [`DataFrame.empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) property to conditionally set the value of the sql statement. If `data1` is empty, then set your `WHERE` clause to something that is False, eg `1 = 0`:

```
if data1.empty:
    sql1 = '''select carrier_name, carrier_account, invoice_number, invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date
              from invoice_summary where 1 = 0'''
else:
    sql1 = ('''select carrier_name, carrier_account, invoice_number, invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date
              from invoice_summary where invoice_number in ({})'''
            .format(','.join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in data1['invoice_number']])))
```

Comment: Not working !.Error `(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "bhx3327983" does not exist in invoice_summary

[SQL: select carrier_name, carrier_account, invoice_number, invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date
from invoice_summary where invoice_number in (BHX3327983)]`

Comment: I updated my answer to enclose each invoice number is quote characters, can you try the updated version with the list comprehension: ie `.format(','.join(["'{}'".format(x) for x in data1['invoice_number']]))`

Comment: if I dont  have any values `data1['invoice_number']`the query breaks i.e that data frame is empty. Is there a way I make this query still to execute without breaking and return no results.

Comment: Added one work-around that conditionally sets the sql query based on `DataFrame.empty`.

Comment: I  was  thinking to create  junk value like `A&&&$$$12` and append into `data1['invoice_number']` so that query will run without error but give the same results.

Comment: No need to modify/append the DataFrame in that case... just if DataFrame.empty: `'''select carrier_name, carrier_account, invoice_number, invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date
              from invoice_summary where invoice_number = 'A&&&$$$12''''` would do

Answer (score 0):

To avoid SQL-injection you could use this :

```
invoice_nums_list = data1['invoice_number'].values.tolist()

sql1 = '''select carrier_name, carrier_account, invoice_number, invoice_amount, currency, invoice_date from invoice_summary where invoice_number in ''' + 
       '(' + ','.join('%s' for i in range(len(invoice_nums_list))) + ')'

print(sql1)

cursor.execute(sql1, params=tuple(invoice_nums_list))
```

Comment: if I dont have any values `data1['invoice_number']`the query breaks i.e that data frame is empty. Is there a way I make this query still to execute without breaking and return no results.

Comment: put `if-else` condition checking `len of data1['invoice_number']` to  define your `sql1`